# An alternative for d3v4 "columns" (I have to use d3v3)

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I need to implement the following code:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
  ...
```

From: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

But, I have to use d3.js version 3. I found 'columns' in the d3 v4 API Reference:

> The returned array also exposes a columns property containing the column names in input order (in contrast to Object.keys, whose iteration order is arbitrary).
>
> For example: data.columns; // ["Year", "Make", "Model", "Length"]

But I'm struggling with coming up with something similar in version 3 to use for the keys variable, as shown at the last line of the quoted code:

```
var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
```

How can I use `data` to get the same `d` and `keys` without the "columns" property?

Comment: Thanks to github there is an old revision of that Bl.ock available which uses D3 **v3**: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3886208/cbaf94ac419f9c3f63fa561b06071c119c5bc0cd

Comment: This will help a lot! Thank you @altocumulus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact that now you know the [v3 version of that bl.ocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817627/an-alternative-for-d3v4-columns-i-have-to-use-d3v3#comment82597977_47817627), it's woth mentioning that it's quite easy to create your own `columns` property, but with some drawbacks.

The [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/master/src/dsv.js#L20) in V4 that creates the `columns` property is this:

```
function inferColumns(rows) {
  var columnSet = Object.create(null),
      columns = [];

  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    for (var column in row) {
      if (!(column in columnSet)) {
        columns.push(columnSet[column] = column);
      }
    }
  });
  return columns;
}
```

We can make a (very) simplified version of it.

Here is a normal `d3.csv` code with D3 v3, I'm loading some CSV I found online:

```js
d3.csv("https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SVU13_7.2.1/com.ibm.ismsaas.doc/reference/AssetsImportMinimumSample.csv?view=kc", function(data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

We can create our `columns` getting the headers of that CSV with:

```
data.columns = d3.keys(data[0])
```

Here is the demo (look at **your browser** console, not the snippet's one):

```js
d3.csv("https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SVU13_7.2.1/com.ibm.ismsaas.doc/reference/AssetsImportMinimumSample.csv?view=kc", function(data){
 data.columns = d3.keys(data[0])
  console.log(data)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

But these are the drawbacks: first, this code is oversimplified: it doesn't take into account duplicated values, for instance. Second, It created the `columns` property **after** loading/parsing the file. Therefore, you cannot use `columns` in the row accessor function, because it doesn't exist at that point. Of corse you could create the `columns` property inside the row function, but that's not a very wise solution, because the row function is called for *every* row in the CSV, which can be hundreds or even thousands.

Comment: How is order maintained in JS engines that don't maintain property order in objects?

Comment: @thephpdev It's not maintained.